# Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i3860/Packages'

Tags: package-management, updates, dpkg, ftp

```
root@debian:~# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i3860/Packages' as repository 'http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i3860'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i3860/Packages' as repository 'http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i3860'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i3860/Packages' as repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i3860'

root@debian:~# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i3860
root@debian:~# dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

I now really dont know how to repair this ? i hit only 4 services is bad or is good ?

folder /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you add contents of `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` to the question.

Comment: I dont have in file dpkg.cfg.d files name multiarch... :/

Comment: :) I'm getting old, may the new release not using that setting file anymore. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i3860` is a wrong name for supported architecture.

1. Fixed it using:

   ```
   dpkg --remove-architecture i3860
   dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```
2. Then update lists again

   ```
   apt update
   ```

Comment: Thanks for you help. <3 Now all is good. Not to think of you over the next years.

Comment: You welcome @PavlikAbraham :)

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved. My solution was to remove the (incorrect) i3860 architecture and add the (correct) i386 architecture.

```
root@debian:~# dpkg --remove-architecture i3860
root@debian:~# dpkg --add-architecture i386
root@debian:~# apt update
Ign:1 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Get:5 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [5,156 B]
Get:7 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages [7,078 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages [455 kB]
Fetched 7,539 kB in 2s (2,985 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@debian:~#
```