# Skippping acquire configured file - doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

When I try updating my Ubuntu 18.04,

I got the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu disco InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

What does it mean?

<strike>I already referred to this question ([Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i3860/Packages'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087754/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i3860-packages)), but by removing the architecture 'i3860" I am not sure it will do any better.</strike>

Is there any other way to remove such message?

Thank you for your kind help. Really appreciate it

Comment: Please add output of `grep -r codelite /etc/apt --include="*.list"` to the question.

Comment: I don't think the linked question is relevant tbh: although your title refers to i**1**386, the message itself says i386 (which is a valid architecture name - although not one that is supported by the codelite repository, at least not for 19.04)

Comment: Which  release really? `lsb_release -rc` please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have Ubuntu version `bionic`, but are looking for files for Ubuntu `disco`.

Locate the file that contains `repos.codelite.org`...

In `terminal`...

`cd /etc/apt` # change directory

`grep -i repos.codelite.org sources.list` # see if it's in this file

`grep -i repos.codelite.org sources.list.d/*.list` # see if it's in one of these files

`sudo -H gedit found_file_name.list` # edit the found .list file

change the line that contans "repos.codelite.org":

```
deb http://xxxxxxxxxx disco xxxx
```

to:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://xxxxxxxxx bionic xxxx
```

**Note: if you have any other references to `disco` in your .list files, change them to `bionic`.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It greatly help solve my problem. Apologies for the late reply.