# N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as ... doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu from version 18.04 to version 20.04.
When I run `sudo apt udate`
I receive the following error:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I also cannot update to Ubuntu 20 when I run `sudo update-manager -d` and I receive the following error:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

update:
The first error was resolved!
But I still cannot update to Ubuntu 20.
when I run `sudo apt update`, I get:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease              
Hit:5 https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease               
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease        
Hit:8 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease    
Get:9 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease [2,456 B]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/smathot/cogscinl/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Fetched 2,456 B in 2s (1,396 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

When I run `sudo apt upgrade`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Following the note from `update`, I run `apt list --upgradable` and the output is

```
python-datamatrix/bionic,bionic 0.10.17-1 all [upgradable from: 0.10.3-1]
```

The default Python version on mu Ubuntu is `Python 3.6.9`

Comment: maybe this can help you? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167703/skippping-acquire-configured-file-doesnt-support-architecture-i386

Comment: and this for the second part of the question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231570/cant-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-because-of-please-install-all-available-upd

Comment: I tried the first link but I don't have any `disco` codename. The skipping acquire error was not resolved.

Comment: I checked the other link before posting this question. 
when I run `apt list --upgradable` the following results: 
`python-datamatrix/bionic,bionic 0.10.17-1 all [upgradable from: 0.10.3-1]`

Comment: the important part of the first link is the one where you look for the string "repos.codelite.org" and add the attribute "[arch=amd64]".

Comment: Thank you very much.. adding `[arch=amd64]` solved mt problem. Any ideas how can solve the `install all available updates for your release before upgrading`? Thanks again!

Comment: could you update your question adding the full output of the command "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe we need to install/update python-datamatrix. Try this: "pip3 install python-datamatrix" and then try to updte the system

Comment: I ran the command several time times and now I get `Requirement already satisfied: python-datamatrix in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.10.7)` but rerunning the `sudo apt update` command have the same output and I still get `python-datamatrix/bionic,bionic 0.10.17-1 all [upgradable from: 0.10.3-1]` message.

Comment: Remove it as suggested by karel in his answer. Replace 'install' with 'uninstall'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, refer to the answer [Skippping acquire configured file - doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167703/skippping-acquire-configured-file-doesnt-support-architecture-i386)
You must find the file located in /etc/apt where the string 'repos.codelite.org' is present and add the string '[arch=amd64]'. In this way only the packages for the correct architecture are installed.

For the second problem (the one related to the OS updated), according to the output you showed in your question, I suggested you to update the package python-datamatrix running: `pip3 install python-datamatrix`

However, according to your feedback (you were not able to solve), it's best to remove it (as suggested in [karel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1249894/1037999)): `pip3 uninstall python-datamatrix`

For this answer, I referred also to [Error while trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10: "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085295/error-while-trying-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-18-10-please-install-all-av) and [Can't upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 because of "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231570/cant-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-because-of-please-install-all-available-upd)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall python-datamatrix with `sudo apt remove python-datamatrix` as it is blocking you from upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. Then you will be able to run `update-manager -d`.

python-datamatrix source code is hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/smathot/python-datamatrix). python-datamatrix can be installed in Ubuntu 20.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python2.7 python-pip  
python -m pip install python-datamatrix
```

python-datamatrix is compatible with Python 2.7 or >= 3.4. If you don't want to install Python 2.7 you can also install it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python3-pip  
python3 -m pip install python-datamatrix
```