# Visual Studio Code intellisense with Unity not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, unity3d

I'm having trouble setting up IntelliSense on vs code. specifically for unity editor. installed mono but I get this error when I run sudo update:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

is there an alternative method to fix this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skippping acquire configured file - doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167703/skippping-acquire-configured-file-doesnt-support-architecture-i386)

Comment: I think so. I’m using Ubuntu 20 so instead of bionic I use focal ?